# Other computers in Gdrive

Tags: google-drive

After I setup sync application from google drive I got disc `Google Drive` in my Windows PC. If I open this disc I have two folders `My Drive` and `Other computers`.

What does `Other computers` is used for? I have several folders in it `My Computer`, `My Laptop`, `My Laptop (1)`, `USB and External Devices`. What is purpose of these folders? Can I somehow setup them?

Comment: How many other devices are you synchronizing with Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

The purposes of these folders is to help you share files between computers. Try it out. Drag some pictures in to there from your laptop and you should be able to find them in the "Other computers" folder on your normal computer.

Comment: But how to know which device is which? I just wandering why I need this functionality. I can create several folders like `Computer1... CompuerN` in `Gdrive`.

Comment: @vico Are you sure that you need to know which device is which? Any file on that Gdrive, regardless of its place, should be visible on all of your machines.